# Error creating dropdown in jsp and struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have this strange issue: my project has a whole lot of dropdowns that are populated from the db. They all work fine except the one gives the following exception (Struts 2.5.26, Java 8 and the struts cdi plugin):

````
```
tag 'select', field 'list', name 'user.role.id': The requested list key 
'viewService.roleList' could not be resolved as a 
collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - 
[unknown location]
org.apache.struts2.components.Component.fieldError(Component.java:257)
org.apache.struts2.components.Component.findValue(Component.java:353)
org.apache.struts2.components.ListUIBean.evaluateExtraParams(ListUIBean.java:81)
org.apache.struts2.components.Select.evaluateExtraParams(Select.java:101)
org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.evaluateParams(UIBean.java:887)
org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:533)
```
````

Here's the jsp:

````
```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>


<html>
<head>
<s:include value="includes/header.jsp"></s:include>
</head>
<body>
<s:include value="includes/menu.jsp"></s:include>
<div class="main">
<h2><s:text name="page.title"/></h2>

    <h1><s:property value="#title"/></h1>
    <s:actionerror />
    <s:actionmessage />
    <s:form action="saveAdmin" method="post">
        <s:textfield key="user.firstname" />

        <s:textfield key="user.lastname" />
        <s:textfield key="user.workPhone" />
        <s:textfield key="user.emailAddress" />

 <s:select label="user.role" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Role"
                                               list="viewService.roleList"
                                               listKey="id"
                                               listValue="roleName"
                                               name="user.role.id"
                                                required="true"/>

        <s:hidden name="user.id" value="%{user.id}"/>

        <s:submit value="Save"/>
        <s:submit value="Back" action="Admin"/>
    </s:form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```
````

And here's viewService - it is an application scoped pojo injected into the Action.

````
```
public List<Role> geRoleList() {
    if (roleList == null)
        this.roleList = persistenceService.getEntities(Role.class);

    LOG.debug("getting roles, size "+roleList.size());
    return roleList;
} 
```
````

Like I said, all my other dropdowns work using the exact same pattern. Why the heck? This is not complicated code. If replace the s:select with any of my other dropdowns it works. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I got this to work by adding this to the Action:
`public List<Role> getRoles() { return viewService.geRoleList();  }` Still don't get why it does not work directly from the service class, like the others...

Comment: where is your `controller` or `test`

Comment: Because `geRoleList` isn’t a getter and `getRoleList` is.

Comment: Oh FFS! Well spotted Dave. Can't believe I wrote this question all because of an f-ing typo.